# Why does vim map with number argument execute more times than expected?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make a simple map in vim to have the `z` key insert 4 blank spaces. I have

```
map z 4i <esc>l
```

If I type `z`, it works as expected. Even typing `z` multiple times works as expected. But when I use something like `2z` it inserts 24 spaces, `1z` inserts 14 spaces. Every time I try to use the repeater it inserts 10 times the repeater spaces, and then 4 more spaces.

Is there something wrong with my map? I want `2z` to insert 8 spaces, `3z` to insert 12 spaces, and so on.

EDIT:
@merlin2011 figured out why my mapping was misbehaving and proposed a working solution to my problem. 
@PeterRincker correctly deduced that the intent of the map was for indentation. The suggestion to use `>>` is better than the mapping with some `.vimrc` modifications:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

The above options allow me to not have to remap any keys and take full advantage of the already functional `>`,`<`,`>>`,`<<` commands. I think this is a better solution to the problem.

Sourced from: [Converting tabs to spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces)

Comment: Exactly, little typo, fixing now.

Comment: Please add a summary of the behaviour to your title.

Comment: I hope you are not using this mapping for indention purposes. It would be better to use `>>`. Your `z` mapping will have a delay because of all the `z` mappings (See `:h z`), e.g. `zz` and `za`.

Comment: @PeterRincker thanks for the insight, I was using it for indentation. Your commend made me check `:h >>` and I've edited my .vimrc to adjust my `shiftwidth`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put a number in front of a mapped command, it is exactly as if you had typed that map command immediately after the number.

In particular, your command `2z` becomes `24i <esc>l`, which will give you 24 spaces.

This behavior is documented in `:help map-examples`.

One workaround is to use 4 literal spaces in the mapping.

```
map z i    <Esc>l
```

Another is to use a function and invoke the function using the mapping.

```
function! Insert(m)
    let l:count = a:m*4
    execute "normal a" . repeat (" ", l:count)
endfunction

map z :<C-U>call Insert(v:count1)<CR>
```

See [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Invoke_a_function_with_a_count_prefix) for a reference on this.

Comment: thanks for the pointer merlin2011, but do you have any suggestions about how to make the map work? Using `map z @='4i <esc>l'` as the man-examples page suggests doesn't work, I get an error `E115: Missing quote: '4i`

Comment: I'm happy with the 4 literal spaces, it works fine for me. I'll likely use the function for a more complex mapping problem.

Comment: You can also use the already available variables `v:count` and `v:count1`.

Comment: @Vitor, My solution already uses this, but if you have a more concise usage, please write a new answer because I want to learn this.

Comment: @BrianAlbertMonroe When I used `v:count` I used it directly inside the function without passing it as an argument, so I was not looking for it in your example in the map. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

It look like this mapping is for indention. It would be best to us Vim's native indention commands:

- `>>` to shift right
- `<<` to shift left
- Use `>` / `<` to shift a visual selections

A common mistake is setting buffer local options like `'shiftwidth'` in your `~/.vimrc` file. It would be best to set these by filetype and use `setlocal` when setting these options. Get the buffer's filetype via: `:set filetype?`

E.g. Assuming filetype is `javascript` then add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugins/javascript.vim`:

```
setlocal shiftwidth = 4
```

It may also be worth looking at [sleuth.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) to automatically adjust your indention settings.

To learn more see the following:

```
:h :setl
:h options
:h after-directory
:h >>
:h 'shiftwidth'
```